# Even if I haven't write margin ,there is a strange margin 12px

Tags: css

I'm novice in css.Could you tell me where is the margin 12px come from?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can also see that It is coming from *user agent stylesheet*. Every browser has some css rule for every element which affects the styling.

You can override this value with your own stylesheet as user agent stylesheet as lowest precedence.

```
p{
  padding:5px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it! Is that -webkit-margin work for it or something else?

Comment: yes `-webkit-margin` is causing the issue. `-webkit-` is used for `-webkit-` browsers.

Answer (score -1):

it's because you have an conflict in your css code, if you want to have 0 margin in this case, you must call "important" at the end of your 0 margin

Comment: Where is the conflict? and `!important` is not the solution. We should try to avoid using `!important` in css.